# laravel: show both a particular post based on id and featured posts in one page

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, post

I have one post information page:- **posts/show.blade.php**.

On this page, I have one post information field and featured posts field.

In my controller, I have already put the following code to show one particular post based on ID.

**ResultsController.php**

```
public function show($id,Post $post)
{
    $post= Post::find($id);
    $post->category;
    $post ->tags;
    return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('results/{id}', 'ResultsController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

**show.blade.php**

```
//one of the cards for featured posts
<div class="image">
    <img src="../image/image2.jpg" alt="" width="300px" height="200px">
</div>
<div class="card-information">
    <div class="event-name">
        lorem
    </div>
    <div class="heart">
        <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: #F70661"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="event-date">
        2019.8.23
    </div>
    <div class="card-info">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet in Lorem, ipsum dolor
            <a href="#" style="color: white">...see more</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But also, I need to show featured events cards bottom of the same page(**show.blade.php**).
I am thinking to add this code to my controller.

```
$posts = Post::latest()->limit(6)->get();
$categories = Category::latest()->limit(6)->get();
```

Because I want to show 6 featured posts.

So the question is how to show one particular post and the featured posts on one page.

I am glad if someone helps me out.

Comment: You want to show latest six posts with some other particular posts?

Comment: You can pass multiple [data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views) to your view: `return view('posts.show', ['post' => $post, 'featuredPosts' => $featuredPosts]);'`

Comment: @ZainFarooq I want to show only one particular post and latest 6 posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kerbholz defined in the comments you can pass multiple data in the view. We can also assign both posts to single array. Your show function should look like this.

```
public function show($id,Post $post)
{
    $particular_post= Post::find($id);
    $featured_posts = Post::latest()->limit(6)->get();
    // we can assign them to an array
    $posts['particular_post'] = $particular_post;
    $posts['featured_posts'] = $featured_posts;
    //here we can pass this array to the compact function
    return view('posts.show',compact('posts'));
}
```

In the view you can access them like this

```
//for featured_posts posts you need foreach loop
 @foreach($posts['featured_posts'] as $featured_post)
 {{ $featured_post->category }}
 @endforeach
 //for particular post you can just echo variable
 {{ $posts['particular_post']->category }}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I will follow your advice !

Comment: Nice. Happy to help you